# requirejs define expected behavior

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm trying to better understand requirejs and have a question on how define() works. I have a simple html page the loads requirejs via the following script tag.

```
<script data-main="scripts/main.js" src="scripts/require.js"></script>
```

main.js contains:

```js
console.log("in main");
require.config({
  baseUrl: 'scripts'
});

define('temp_module', ['module3'], function(t) {
  console.log("ta: ", t);
  return {
    "sundry": t.input
  }
});
```

module3.js contains:

```js
define(function() {

  return {
    input: "output"
  }
});
```

What I expected is the the define statement will define and cache a new module named 'temp_module' depending on what is returned from the callback function. The callback function takes in the return value of module3. At this point both temp_module and module3 are cached if needed later.

Clearly that is not how this is supposed to behave as I only get the "in main" output in the console and not the console.log from the callback function.

Can anyone correct my understanding on how this should work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The missing piece is that you do not have anything that requires the loading of `temp_module`. When RequireJS processes `data-main="scripts/main.js"` it is looking for a module named `main`. It finds your file `scripts/main.js`, and executes it but there is no *module* named `main` in it, so the loading ends right there.

You could change the name of `temp_module` to `main`, or remove the name entirely, and then it should work.

When you remove the name, what you have is an anonymous `define` call. RequireJS allows one anonymous `define` call per file. An anonymous `define` call gets a module name associated with it at loading time. RequireJS uses the module name that was used when the module was requested and associates this name to the `define`. In your case the name would be `main`. This is because your module is required through the `data-main` attribute, and this attribute is subject to some special handling because it has to serve to provide both a *path* to load a module and an initial *module name*. When RequireJS processes your `data-main` value, it uses that value literally to determine path to load. However, it makes a module name by dropping the `.js` and by keeping only the last part of the path so from `scripts/main.js` it gets the module name `main`. Then it loads the file at the path and looks for the module named `main` in your file. Since there is only a single anonymous `define`, it takes that `define` as defining the `main` module and calls the callback.

Comment: Thanks. Why does not supplying an ID (or supplying and ID of 'main') to define() cause it to then call the callback function?

Comment: Thanks, very helpful.  Let me try to restate that accurately. After removing 'temp_module', the anonymous define in main.js is assigned an ID of main. The reference to main via the original script tag is an implicit require() and therefore the define in main calls the callback function. Is that accurate?

Answer (score 0):

A defined module is not "loaded" until it's required (included) by someone.

In your main.js just do:

```
require([ 'module3' ], function (module3) {
  ...
});
```

Also, avoid giving explicit names to your modules yourself (like "temp_module") unless you have a specific reason to. Let RequireJS give modules names based on their paths.